# Vaadin 8. Компонент Upload. Нужно ли закрывать OutputStream?

Tags: java, vaadin

Код взят для примера с офф сайта ваадина:

```
class ImageUploader implements Receiver, SucceededListener {
public File file;

public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                  String mimeType) {
    // Create and return a file output stream
    ...
}

public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
    // Show the uploaded file in the image viewer
    image.setSource(new FileResource(file));
}
```

};

Функция `receiveUpload ()` возвращает поток типа `OutputStream`, нужно ли закрывать этот поток? И как? Ведь экземпляра потока в явном виде нет.

Comment: А разве вы не должны реализовать этот метод? Я предполагаю, что закрывать не нужно, так как этот поток как раз используется клиентом этого класса. Как я вижу использование: Вам дается информация о запрашиваемом файле, вы как хотите получаете выходной поток (из реального файла, БД, сокета, и т.д.) и возвращаете. Клиент не в курсе откуда взят файл.

Comment: Как я понимаю, через этот поток передается файл и, если загрузка прошла успешно, вызывается функция uploadSucceeded где уже можно работать с этим файлом. на данный момент я закрываю поток как раз в этой функции вручную, но стоит ли это делать?